# Pull files into web dir from git repo

Tags: git, push, live

I've seen many pages and posts about this and not one of them works on my Digital Ocean droplet.

I have a live rails app deployed with Capistrano, which means I had to push it to the server with Git before deploying. So Git works.
Yet, now I want to update the site with some changes and while the remote repo is up to date (verified with `git log`), the web directory is not up to date.

I know I need to get the new files across to that dir, but how?

hooks/post-receive:

```
#!/bin/sh
git checkout -f
```

Nada.
I also ran `sudo ./post-receive`, just to be sure the post-receive hook executed (yes, it is executable). No output. Just another CLI prompt.

Why is it so ridiculously difficult to get a folder to contain the latest git push??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push-to-deploy+hook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an `unset GIT_DIR` line, assuming your hook is in a bare repository (one without checked out files) in `myrepo.git/hooks`

```
#!/bin/sh
unset GIT_DIR
cd /path/to/checkout/repository
git pull
git checkout -f
```

The unset will make sure Git will consider your checked out repository as the current one (instead of the bare repo)

Comment: So what exactly is necessary to get a git push to update the web dir? I create a repo with or without `--bare`? Does it have to be called `.git` or `ProjectName.git`?
Does it need to be inside the project folder to work? And do I need to have an empty folder and push the code for the first time to this repo in order to be able to update it with `git push origin master`?
When I created a non-bare repo, it looked like it was going to update the live dir, but after pushing the project, failed with 'merge would overwrite README.txt'. Deleted file, retried. Same error for next file...

Comment: @Kane If you push, the best practice is to push to a bare repo, inside which you put your postreceive hook, which will then update the non-bare repo.

Comment: So the bare repo is in a non-web dir like /home/deployuser and the post-receive hook pushes it again to the non-bare in webroot/projectname/.git. Is that correct?
How do you push from one repo to another on the same server?
My experience with git so far is limited to pushing to remote server. I am learning but it is confusing...

Comment: @Kane the post-receive does not push: it changes folder to the actual non-bare repo, and pull from the bare repo.

Comment: Ok. So to make sure I understand it, the post-receive hook is in the bare repo where I push my code (in the hooks dir). It changes directory to the project path with cd to the project path and the git pull is performed from that path with `git pull` and then `git checkout -f`
So it is checking out the bare repo because the hook is being executed from that dir.
Is that correct?

Comment: It does check out the non-bare repo, but after pulling from from the bare repo, so the content of the non-bare repo is updated, and the checkout reflect that updated content.

Comment: I think I get it now. Thank you for explaining. I'll try it out now and see if I can get the darned thing updated...

Comment: Hmm. My bare repo is now up to date but the post-receive hook returns error:
`fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born` I found an article that says I need to commit something to the repo to create the master branch but I pushed a whole project and it still has this message. Is there something to set?

Comment: It seems that this did actually work, as my latest code is in the web directory. Quite why it is still serving old code is the next issue but thank you for your help with this. @VonC